# Apache2 Doesn't Work - Nameserver isnt correct

Tags: server, apache2

I want to give a HTTPS connection to my website, so I created a SSL Certificate. When I try to restart Apache2, it throws this error:

`Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`
This is my config (in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin enderf5027@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Please add

```
ServerName example.com
```

on webserver conf and try to reload webserver .

Comment: Nothing happened. I tried example.com and my domain too but i didn’t work. For reload, I used sudo systemctl reload apache2